# Convert.ChangeType from int to bool

Tags: c#, int, boolean

Using the following to get values from query string and convert to specific types should there be a need.

```
public static T Convert<T>(NameValueCollection QueryString, string KeyName, T DefaultValue) where T : IConvertible
    {
        //Get the attribute
        string KeyValue = QueryString[KeyName];

        //Not exists?
        if (KeyValue == null) return DefaultValue;

        //Empty?
        if (KeyValue == "") return DefaultValue;

        //Convert
        try
        {
            return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(KeyValue, typeof(T));
        }
        catch
        {
            return DefaultValue;
        }
    }
```

A call would be made as such

```
int var1 = Convert<int>(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString,"ID", 0);
```

However when trying to do the following it does not work correctly so my question is, is it possible to change the code to handle bools if the value being retrieved from the querystring variable is a 1 or a 0 instead of a true of false.

```
ie... instead of
http://localhost/default.aspx?IncludeSubs=true
the call is
http://localhost/default.aspx?IncludeSubs=1

bool var1 = Convert<bool>(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString,"IncludeSubs", false);
```

Comment: What does "it does not work correctly" mean?  Be explicit about what goes wrong, we can't guess at it.

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType("1", typeof(bool))` (passing a `string`) does not work. `Convert.ChangeType(1, typeof(bool))` (passing an `int`) does.

Comment: I apologize for not getting overly specific.  The line QueryString[KeyName] returns the value of whatever it retrieves as as string... so it essentially gets passed in as viewed in your first line in your response.  The Exception I receive is "String was not recognized as a valid boolean"

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a method Like Convert.ToBoolean(stringval) but without being specific to boolean...  if I TYPE the method T the convert.changetype will know that if I get a string and pass in a number other than 0 it will be result in true

Answer (score 8):

You can modify your convert method in order to handle booleans as following:

```
//Convert
try
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    if(type == typeof(bool))
    {
        bool boolValue;
        if(bool.TryParse(KeyValue, out boolValue))
            return boolValue;
        else
        {
            int intValue;
            if(int.TryParse(KeyValue, out intValue))
                return System.Convert.ChangeType(intValue, type);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(KeyValue, type);
    }
}
catch
{
    return DefaultValue;
}
```

In this way you can convert to boolean values like: `"true"`, `"False"`, `"0"`, `"1"`

Comment: This was something I thought of doing but it then makes a generic method a little less generic by placing specific type testing within the method body.  It does present a possible solution but I was hoping there was something built in that could handle the conversion for me without putting in type specific information.